# rpm build specfile how can I resolve conflicts with require rpm

Tags: centos7, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am writing a spec file for a new RPM package (b2) that updates package (b1), and depends on another RPM package (a).

The packages have the following scenario:

- my new RPM package (b2) has directories that will be deleted during
  the update
- the required RPM package (a) has exactly the same directories.

When running yum update, I get the following behaviour:

- resolves dependencies (ok)
- transaction test (not ok)
- old files from old package (b1) are still there, and there are conflicts with package a

Question:

- Is it possible to solve these problems?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can include real examples (your spec file, output/error logs, etc)

Comment: This makes no sense - "`b2` has directories that will be deleted during the update" - what update? It's the new one?

Comment: b2 is an update for package b1, b1 contains path xyz, b2 doesn't, b2 contains the 'requires: a' statement, package a contains path xyz - my problem is the update from package b1 to b2

Comment: two packages cannot "contain" or "own" the same files. Seems like you need to create a new version of package `a` that doesn't own the files anymore that `b` now owns.